# Grouped Barplot with three measures

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to reproduce the following graph in R which is generated via Excel.

[image: Excel Plot]

The CSV file has following content:

```
> myd
  type       am      tae      tac
1   kA 81.73212 73.07151 26.92849
2   kI 78.87324 84.50704 15.49296
3   kL 82.52184 69.91262 30.08738
4   kS 82.67147 69.31411 30.68589
5   sA 81.67176 73.31295 26.68705
6   sI 79.54135 81.83460 18.16540
7   sL 81.58485 73.66061 26.33939
8   sS 82.09616 71.61536 28.38464
```

The following R code creates `am` on the y axis, but I also want to add `tae` and `tac`.

```
ggplot(myd, aes(x=type, y=am)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: Plot from R with ggplot]

Do you know how I can add this in R to have it like in the Excel diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(reshape2)
myd_molten <- melt(data = myd, id.vars = "type")

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(myd_molten, aes(x = type, y = value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
gather(myd, Var, Val, am:tac) %>% 
       ggplot(., aes(x=type, y=Val))+
       geom_bar(aes(fill=Var), position='dodge', stat='identity')+
       coord_flip()
```